# Expected a step @ line 37, column 17. try{

Tags: jenkins, groovy, try-catch

i am trying to use try catch inside stage but getting error as mentioned in subject.
Here i am using build job to call another jenkins pipeline which works without try-catch.
Not sure if we can use try-catch outside shell with build job ?. \n
\n Requirement is to use try catch with build job so that in case of any failure , it will skip this step, echo message and go to next step.

```
{
   stage('Pull Pipeline') {
        try {
            build job: "../new pipeline/test_dummy", wait: true
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            echo "release having error"
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is a declarative pipeline, the `try catch` block should be wrapped by a `scrip {}` block as it is scripted pipeline syntax: `script { try { ...} catch {...} }`.

Comment: thank you Noam , can you please help here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71902367/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-such-dsl-method-initenvconfig